# how to generate GUID for one element of a list<T> In MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, guid

I have created a class in Model , which will be my database table shown in view.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace showtable.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public Guid  EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime hiredate { get; set; }
        public decimal salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now i want to generate a GUID for primary key which is EmployeeId.
how to write it in my controller?

Comment: its actually a list < employee> . i want to add values to each records.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid  EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime hiredate { get; set; }
    public decimal salary { get; set; }

    public Employee () 
    {
       EmployeeId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

And then in your controller when you instantiate a new `Employee` class the you would have the `EmployeeId` property populated with an `GUID`.

Comment: can you say that exactly ?

Comment: What? If you mean that the property will have an unique `GUID` assigned when creating a new instance of the class, then yes.